# Using MySQL to generate image array for Supersized

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, background-image, supersized

I would like to have a database list of all of the background images on my server and randomly pick 5 to show when a user uploads the page (so that there is less drain on my server while still showing all 40 or so background shots that I want to include).

I am incredibly new to Javascript, but am experienced with MySQL so if you could give your answer in the syntax of something like:

```
<javascript code>
//Enter MySQL here
<javascript code?
```

I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you writing something in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are looking for the functionality that AJAX has. A good library to start with would be jQuery (jquery.com), which includes ajax. This way you can have a server-side script (maybe written in PHP?) which runs some of the MySQL code when your ajax function is called and sends a response with some pictures.

here is a basic tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

here is the API: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: but as tadman says, unless this is server side javascript like nodeJS, then there is no easy way to access mysql the way you put it.

Comment: what kind of server do you have? a LAMP stack? (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP)

Comment: I have an apache server, but i am looking to access the Database information using MySQL

Comment: Well if you are intent on connecting to MySQLthrough  you'll have to do some heavy searching for libraries which will allow you to do that. I personally don't know of any.

Comment: I would think that you need php, java, ruby, etc to access the database server-side and send a reply which JavaScript can understand.